# How to implement android localization +

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application I want to implement the android localization functionality. I have a database, it is filled with full of strings in two  different languages. How can I implement the android localization on the database. Please provide your suggestions and possible please provide good examples or tutorials.

Comment: u should copy all strings to `strings.xml` in corresponding `values` folder..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can get current locale using

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault(); // current locale
Locale locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;  or you can ...
Log.d(logtag, "lang = " + locale.getLanguage());
```

and fetch your strings from DB according to locale.

and you can read more about **multilingual Android apps on following [link](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here I have added tamil language localization to text using "BhashaSETTSinhalaTamil.ttf" font
Same as this you can use other font files to add localization.

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BhashaSETTSinhalaTamil.ttf");
        paragraphe1.setTypeface(font);
paragraphe1.setText("இது மத்திய மலை நாட்டின்");
```